# Couldn't apply javascript to my template in flask despite having it in the static dir. How do I resolve that in the code below?

Tags: javascript, html, flask, frontend

I have a flask project in which I'm trying to make a **tree** structure but I don't think the JS is being applied to my `tree.html` as it couldn't expand the options. Below is the code that I found in internet which I'm trying to make work as I don't have any frontend experience. I'd be grateful for your help.

**Base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jsfun.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**tree.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <ul class="tree">
        <li><a href="#">Part 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Part 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Part 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item A</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item B</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item C</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item D</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item E</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**jsfun.js**

```
var tree = document.querySelectorAll('ul.tree a:not(:last-child)');
for(var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++){
    tree[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        var parent = e.target.parentElement;
        var classList = parent.classList;
        if(classList.contains("open")) {
            classList.remove('open');
            var opensubs = parent.querySelectorAll(':scope .open');
            for(var i = 0; i < opensubs.length; i++){
                opensubs[i].classList.remove('open');
            }
        } else {
            classList.add('open');
        }
    });
}
```

Here's when the page opens
[image: page opens]

And nothing happens when I click any item:

[image: After clicking any item]

Comment: Here's the link where I found this code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636375/how-to-create-a-collapsing-tree-table-in-html-css-js

Comment: Is javascript file is being served from the Flask server? check under `Sources` tab in chrome devtools.

Comment: @Pradeepb No, it's not. I can't seem to figure out why! Please help.

Comment: @Pradeepb I've even added the js code internally into my html code. Still it's not working.

Comment: I tried putting it in html page and its working fine.

Comment: @Pradeepb Could you please share the code in the answer? I'd be highly grateful. Thanks

Comment: sure. I am working on serving the js file now. together I will share it.

Comment: @Pradeepb Thanks a million. I'm looking forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://github.com/pradeepb6/test_app) repo. Check where you are making a mistake. I believe its the way you are importing the `js` file. you should use like below

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jsfun.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you again. I added the 'js' and 'css' folder and gave their path and now it's working fine. I don't know why's that since I had both files in static dir and I was giving their proper path.

Comment: Maybe flask expects you to put css and js files in their respective directory.

Comment: Thats how Flask works. it will create a url path using `url_for('static')` and then it will serve the files in that path.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for taking the time to do all this. May Python bless you :)

Comment: Ha ha. Thanks Anand :)