# Spacing in HTML along with Collapsible text sections

Tags: html, asp.net, bash

After already writing 3000 lines of the following text structure, I realized that I want to make certain sections of the text collapsible. I am currently using `<code class="language-bash" data-lang="bash">` to account for spacing structure that I manually created. Only reason I'm using bash is because I found a template that was doing the same sentence structure and I just adjusted the text.

Here is a sample of the code in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7stnjkj4/1/

What would be the best option from this point?

Answer (score 0):

you want to make Collapsible text section right ?

Comment: Yes, that is the goal. I want to have a collapsible point at Nav, Customer Maintenance and Customer.

Comment: here is a simple way to create a collapsible text section by using bootstrap.check this https://jsfiddle.net/codegen/aoabp9v0/

Comment: That would work except that I can't use `<div>` within `<code>`

Comment: Decided to drop the 3k lines and go with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636375/how-to-create-a-collapsing-tree-table-in-html-css-js